# How to use selected value as table name for another select in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with two coloms source_name and output_name:

```
CREATE TABLE all_table(
  source_name text,
  target_name text
);
```

Source name it is some external data name. Target name it is auto-generated table name in my DB. There is a relationship between the source name and the target name, there is only one target name for each source name.
I have additional table in DB:

```
CREATE TABLE output_table_1(
  first_name text,
  second_name text,
  birthday timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE output_table_2(
  login text,
  money int
);
```

In table "all_table" I have some rows:

```
|   source_name |    target_name |
|---------------|----------------|
| personal data | output_table_1 |
|    login data | output_table_2 |
```

I want select information from correct table by source name. So I tried

```
WITH selected_table AS (
  SELECT target_name FROM all_table WHERE source_name='personal data'
)
SELECT * FROM selected_table;

And also

SELECT first_name FROM 
(SELECT target_name FROM all_table WHERE source_name='personal data') AS out_table;
```

But Postgres print me only correct target name

```
|    target_name |
|----------------|
| output_table_1 |
```

I want to get something similar on my query

```
| first_name | second_name | birthday |
|------------|-------------|----------|
|     FName1 |      SName1 |    Date1 |
|     FName2 |      SName2 |    Date2 |
|     FName3 |      SName3 |    Date3 |
|     FName4 |      SName4 |    Date4 |
|        ... |         ... |      ... |
```

I've also tried this query

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %s LIMIT 10', (SELECT target_name FROM all_table WHERE source_name='personal data'));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Query executed but nothing happened.
Surfing on Google doesn't do anything useful. But mb I'm bad in this.

> ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to obtain data from DO block you need to define cursor for query.

```
do
$$
declare 
    _query text ;
    _cursor CONSTANT refcursor :='_cursor';
begin
    _query:='Select * from '||(Select tab_name from ... where ..);
    open _cursor for execute _query;
end;
$$;
fetch all from _cursor;
```

Comment: It is always better to use `format` instead of simply concatenating the strings with `||`.

Comment: Sure. Lack of cursor was crucial. open cursor for execute format(..  etc would work.